# Learning Java Face Recognition Technology

Tags: java, face-recognition

First, I will explain my situation. I am 22. Final year - BSc Software Development. I am self learning advanced technologies. Now the question.

I am seeking to learn "Java Face Recognition technology". I googled it and found same question in here too. But they didn't help because the questions were asked by people who know the technology already, so they are not suitable for a beginner that who don't know anything about this. The only face recognition I liked is face.com. But, they didn't provide a proper tutorial because it is not only for Java.

Please be kind enough to help me to learn this technology. I need tutorials/books/PDF to learn it. And yes, I am a beginner for this, so I need to do it from the beginner level. Really glad if you can help me.

Comment: To properly learn face detection/recognition technologies, you should stop getting hold of a specific language - especially one that's not well-suited to AI and image processing. Just look for papers and code, learn and experiment. Also, check OpenCV. It has some good tutorials about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182849/face-detection-in-java) previous SO post and [this](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/nui08/) page seem to be like a good way to start. One of the most basic ideas seems to use [Eigen Faces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) (there should be more information [here](http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/PCA/jcn.pdf)) and combine it with an imaging library such as [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) (which is a wrapper for [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)).

I think that this should get you started in the right direction. Face recognition is, in my opinion an area devoted to a mix of AI and image processing techniques, so I do not think that you will find a single location which contains all the information about the subject.

My recommendation would be to read through the resources which are available and then decide what you are going to use and how.

Comment: Seems to be nice. Thanks for the reply. I am on my way.

Others, please reply if you know something too.

Comment: @user1484871: If you leave the question for a few days you should be able to get other responses. The *problem*, so to speak, with your question is that it is quite open ended for someone to provide you with a specific answer.

Comment: Mister, I don't know who you are, but you just opened me a WHOLE NEW WORLD! The link you gave is to a chapter on "Killer Game Programming - Java" book. I checked it, and it has all the things I struggled to learn! Running to the international book store now! Thanks Mister :)

Comment: @user1484871: Glad it worked out for you. If this answer helped you then please mark it :).